# TensorFlow Variable not being restored correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and am trying to learn to save and restore my model.

I saved it like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
         #Training Model...

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print(sess.run('b1:0'))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.save(sess, r"C:\...\Desktop\model.ckpt")
```

And Restoring this model like this:

```
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'C:\...\Desktop\model.ckpt.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint("C:/.../Desktop"))
print(sess.run('b1:0'))
```

But the values in b1 are different in each program. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the default graph before creating the new session? I had a similar issue and I think that resolved it for me. Command is `tf.reset_default_graph()`.

Comment: No. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to "solve" the problem. Not really solve it, but I just realized that the model actually works the way it is suppose to. The fact that the values of the weights change is related to using Session.run() on a tensor.

I still can't explain why the values of the weights change. But as the model works, I guess there isn't really a problem to solve.